# Why does this particular React router configuration not work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The code below will render a link that I can click on, and when I click on it, I can see the URL changing to have `/japanese_game` for the URL path. However... nothing appears to change on the page, the link that says "Japanese" is still there, unchanged. It should display the other stuff in `<Route path="/japanese_game">`, or rather, that's what I would like it to do.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App container">
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Link to="/japanese_game">
                            <div className="language-option">
                                Japanese
                                日本語
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/japanese_game">
                        <h1>Japanese Game</h1>
                        <Link to="/">
                            Go back
                        </Link>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the order, it compares and selects on the basis of which matches first. put the Route with "/japanese_game" first.

Answer (score 1):

The `<Switch>` component render the first route he match ([doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)).

When you go to `/japanese_game`, you also hit `/` route, so he render the component under the `/` route.

To prevent that, you have 2 options:

1. Add an `exact` props to your route `/` : `<Route exact path="/">` (hightly recommanded)
2. Change the ordre of your route (not recommanded at all)

Comment: This actually makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the routes or alternatively use an "exact" flag.

`<Route exact path="/japanese_game">`